# FFmpeg java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen failed: library "libavutil.so" not found in Vivo model device

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Facing a lot of crashes in the Android Vivo devices with the above error. Can I restrict this to the Vivo models in Android.

I'm using the implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4'

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen failed: library "libavutil.so" not found

init {
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("avutil")
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec")
        System.loadLibrary("avformat")
        System.loadLibrary("swscale")
        System.loadLibrary("avfilter")
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Log.i("error","${e.message}")
    }
}
```

In app/build.gradle

> ndk {
> abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' }

Note: If I migrate to the latest version ffmpeg-kit-full:6.0-2

Clarifications:

1. Shall I need to add this below in the code as well if I use the FFmpeg-kit
2. If I did not need to use means, does it make any issues in the app?.(i.e) if I removed
3. Shall I need to add any additional loadlibrary in the init?
4. Is there any simple fix for the above error for Oppo alone without migrating?
5. Shall I need to add these architectures in ndk of my app?

> arm-v7a, arm-v7a-neon, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64 architectures

```
 init {
        try{
            System.loadLibrary("avutil")
            System.loadLibrary("avcodec")
            System.loadLibrary("avformat")
            System.loadLibrary("swscale")
            System.loadLibrary("avfilter")
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            Log.i("error","${e.message}")
        }
    }
```